# linux shell get multi file intersection

Tags: linux, shell

I have a few txt file examples 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt
I want to get 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt content intersection

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt | sort | uniq -c > tmp.txt
cat tmp.txt 3.txt | sort | uniq -c > tmp2.txt 
and so on ....
```

Is there a better way?

```
input text
1.txt
1
2
3
4

2.txt
1
2
3

3.txt
1
2

4.txt
1
5

expected output:
1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do add samples of **input** and expected **output** in your question in text form, thank you.

Comment: input text
1.txt
1
2
3
4

2.txt
1
2
3

3.txt
1
2

4.txt
1
5

expected output:
1

Comment: Kindly update them in your question, comments are not meant to be having codes/samples, thank you.

Comment: sorry , okay question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

***1st solution:*** This considers that you may have **duplicates** values of lines with in a single Input_file itself then you may try following:

```
awk '
!arr2[FILENAME,$0]++{
  arr1[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i in arr1){
    if(arr1[i]==(ARGC-1)){
       print i
    }
  }
}
' *.txt
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** This solution assumes that there is **no duplicates** in Input_file if this is the case then try following:

```bash
awk '
{
  arr[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    if(arr[i]==(ARGC-1)){
       print i
    }
  }
}
' *.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  arr[$0]++                ##Creating an array named arr with index of $0 and keep increasing its value.
}
END{                       ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in arr){           ##Traversing through array arr here.
    if(arr[i]==(ARGC-1)){  ##Checking condition if value of current item in arr is Equal to total number of files then print it.
       print i
    }
  }
}
' *.txt                    ##Passing all .txt files as an input to awk program from here.
```